# Executing killall command from Java

Tags: java, macos, kill-process

I have to execute a command on Mac OS:

```
killall -KILL "Google Chrome"
```

When I execute it in terminal or run a .command file with this command it works.

I tried this all in Java code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/killall -KILL \"Google Chrome\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall -KILL \"Google Chrome\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"killall -KILL \\\"Google Chrome\\\"\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c \"killall -KILL \\\"Google Chrome\\\"\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/killall", new String[]{"-KILL", "Google Chrome"});
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall", new String[]{"-KILL", "Google Chrome"});
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash", new String[]{"-c", "killall -KILL \"Google Chrome\""});
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash", new String[]{"-c", "killall -KILL \"Google Chrome\""});
```

And it doesn't work.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
String cmds[] = {"killall","Google Chrome"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])

Comment: Yes, that's right. I used wrong variants with exec(String) and exec(String, String[]) and totally missed the right one: exec(String[]). Thank you!

Comment: @user2780836 If this is your favorite correct answer feel free to mark it as such with the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
String[] command = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-KILL", "Google Chrome" };

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

You could also try the above, by adding quotes to Google Chrome as follows:

```
String[] command = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-KILL","\"Google Chrome\"" };
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. I used wrong variants with exec(String) and exec(String, String[]) and totally missed the right one: exec(String[]). Thank you!